# DOM events using jQuery/Javascript are working only on $().ready or window.onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, event-handling, jquery-events

My jQuery code adds a class to an element on button click. The code works only if I pass it to `$(document).ready()`. Same applies to Javascript, the code works fine only if I use `window.onload`. What is the reason for this behavior? My .js file is in the 'head' section of HTML and it's already read during browser's rendering of HTML page.

```
$('#switcher-large').on('click', function(){
   $('#content').addClass('large');
});

var docId = document.getElementById('switcher-large');
docId.onclick = function(){
    var content = document.getElementById('content').classList.add('large');
}
```

Working code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#switcher-large').on('click', function(){
        $('#content').addClass('large');
    });
});

window.onload = function(){
    var docId = document.getElementById('switcher-large');
    docId.onclick = function(){
        var content = document.getElementById('content').classList.add('large');
    }
}
```

Comment: This is because your script is executing before the rest of the page is fully loaded so it doesnt find the element and fails. You should see the errors if you open console in devtools in your browser. `$(document).ready` will delay execution of script until DOM is fully loaded so element will be found that time.

Answer (score 1):

An HTML page can't be manipulated safely until the document is `ready`. You have added your `js` tags in the starting of the document, in the `<head>` even before the `<body>` is written. So, if you are manipulating something from the `<body>` contents, it is not present at the time of execution. Now content under `$(document).ready(function(){}`  execute when the whole HTML document is ready and all elements are present in the document. So when you use ::

```
$('#switcher-large').on('click', function(){
   $('#content').addClass('large');
});
```

It will execute `before` you button with id `#switcher-large` loaded in the document.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the document lifecycle to understand this behavior.
The browser will execute all scripts before the DOM is ready therefor no event is attached since the element was not there when script executed.

**window.onload** is triggered after DOM is built and all resources are loaded (eg: images) now all elements are available and the script will work fine.

For more information read this page
https://javascript.info/onload-ondomcontentloaded#domcontentloaded

Answer (score 1):

It's because your html hasn't rendered yet.
Think of the browser reading your page line by line and executing whatever you are asking it to execute, so if you are telling it to get an element before it processes the element, it won't be able to do so.

Beside, in the onload event you can also put the script after the elements (for better understanding of how things works, your way, using onload, is perfectly fine if not better):

```
<span id="content">Hello StackOverflow!</span>
<button type="button" id="switcher-large">&#x1F50E;</button>
<script>
    var docId = document.getElementById('switcher-large');
    docId.onclick = function(){
        var content = document.getElementById('content').classList.add('large');
    };
</script>
```